# How to insert a maximum value plus one in opencart model file applications using twig file

Tags: opencart

How to insert a maximum value plus one in sql model query..

Problem:
Array ( [MAX( sort )] => 64 ).
How to split array value.

Comment: Please clarify your question? What does "plus one" mean? Where is there any model or twig file?

Comment: Nico Haase...In model file

Comment: array spliting??

Comment: How to split an array is a question that is not that difficult to find answered on Google or even in the PHP documentation. Can you share the code you already have and give a clear question about what is not working as expected?

Comment: Array ( [MAX( sort )] => 64 )...This is the value Okay.

Comment: I need sort=64 thats all